# HTML elements on page load & window re-size in Safari not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Am new to using JS and Jquery but am trying to fix some cross browser styling issues.

I have three different pages which use similar div elements

**Products Page**

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <a class="autoHeight">
         <img></img>
         <div>
              <p></p>
          </div>
      </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

**Clients Page**

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="autoheight">
         <img></img>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

**Cases Page**

```
<section>
  <ul class="result">
    <li>
     <a class="autoHeight">
         <img></img>
         <div>
              <h2></h2>
              <p></p>
          </div>
      </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.autoheight {
   height: auto; 
   /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

Each page displays a list of these items and the element with the class "autoheight" sets the elements height using J Query during page load or when the window is re-sized.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).resize(function () {
        $('nav ul li > ul').css({ 'display': 'none', 'opacity': '0' });
        if ($('#openMenu').css('display') === 'block') {
            /* mobile size */
            $('.subMenuOpen').addClass('subMenu').removeClass('subMenuOpen'); // set the - icons back to a +
            $('nav').css({ 'display': 'none', 'right': '-60%', 'position': 'absolute' });
            $('#openMenu').css({ 'background-image': "url('/img/menu_open.png')" });
            $('#openMenu').className = "menuOpen";
            $('#container').css({ 'left': '0' });
            mobileDOM();
            // product submenu
            $('#product div#productsubsectionnav ul li').css({ 'color': defaultColour, 'background-color': 'white' });
            $('.productsubsectionnavActive').css({ 'color': colourScheme });
        } else {
            /* desktop size */
            $('nav > ul > li > a').removeClass('subMenuOpen');
            var navContent = $("nav > ul").length;
            if (navContent > 1) {
                $('#container').css({ 'left': '0' });
                $('nav').css({ 'display': 'block', 'position': 'relative', 'right': '0' });
                $("nav > ul:nth-child(3)").appendTo($("header > div div:nth-child(2)"));
                $("nav form").appendTo($("header > div div:nth-child(2) ul > li:last-of-type"));
            }
            // product submenu
            $('#product div#productsubsectionnav ul li').css({ 'color': defaultColour, 'background-color': defaultColour });
            $('.productsubsectionnavActive').css({ 'color': colourScheme, 'background-color': colourScheme });
        }
        pdms.utilities.setHeights('.autoHeight'); 
    }).resize();

pdms.utilities.setHeights('.autoHeight'); 
});
```

**ultilites script**

```
var pdms = pdms || {};

pdms.utilities = {
    setHeights: function (selector) {
        if ($('.autoHeight').css('background-color') == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
            console.log("setHeights " + selector);
            $(selector).css('height', 'auto');
            setTimeout(function () {
                var heights = $(selector).map(function () {
                    return $(this).height();
                });
                $(selector).height(Math.max.apply(this, heights));
            }, 300);
        } else
        {
            $(selector).css('height', 'auto');
        }

    },

    validateClientLoginForm: function () {
        var itemNumber = $('#item_number').val();
        var itemAmount = $('#amount').val();
        if (itemNumber == "" || itemAmount == "") {
            alert("Please complete invoice number and amount")
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
};
```

All pages render fine and behave as expected in all browsers except for Safari. In safari the element with auto height doesn't set the height until I either reload the page or move the window.

I've tried to wrap the a elements in a div and give that div the class "autoHeight" but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference. I've a feeling it's something simple but am too much of a novice to notice it, this one has me stumped.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: firstly, on the _Clients Page_ replace `<div class=""autoheight>` with `<div class="autoheight">` and its corresponding closing tag `<div>` with `</div>`.

Comment: yep sorry, that was just a typo when typing out. it's not like that in the code itself.